# How to sum the total price from products and courses?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables of products and a courses table.

Every cart has many products and courses.

The product price gets multiplied by the amount ordered and then stored inside a row called total on the pivot table.

The course price gets multiplied by the amount ordered and then stored inside a row called total on the pivot table.

So each order has an array of various products and courses with each a row called total that stores the total price.

Until here everything works fine.

Now I´m trying to make a total sum for each order.

I try to make an overview with every order and his total. So the result is 0.

I did a lot of research but I have still no clue how to write this in a function.

[image: table]

```
@php
    $totalPrice = 0;
    foreach (App\Services\Cart\Cart::all() as $cart) {
       if (isset($cart['product']) && isset($cart['course'])) {
          $productPrice = intval($cart['product']->price);
          $coursePrice = intval($cart['course']->price);
          $totalPrice += ($productPrice + $coursePrice) * $cart['quantity'];
       }
    }
    $totalPrice = number_format($totalPrice);
@endphp
<div class="text-large"><strong>{{ $totalPrice }} $</strong></div>
```

When I replaced these codes.

```
@php
    $totalPrice = 0;
    foreach (App\Services\Cart\Cart::all() as $cart) {
        $productPrice = intval($cart['product']->price);
        $coursePrice = intval($cart['course']->price);
        $totalPrice += ($productPrice + $coursePrice) * $cart['quantity'];
    }
    $totalPrice = number_format($totalPrice);
@endphp
<div class="text-large"><strong>{{ $totalPrice }} $</strong></div>
```

App\Services\Cart\Cart.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Cart;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Cart
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cart = session()->get('cart') ?? collect([]);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $value
     * @param null $obj
     * @return $this
     */
    public function put(array $value , $obj = null)
    {
        if(!is_null($obj) && $obj instanceof Model) {
            $value = array_merge($value , [
                'id' => Str::random(10),
                'subject_id' => $obj->id,
                'subject_type' => get_class($obj)
            ]);
        } elseif(!isset($value['id'])) {
            $value = array_merge($value , [
                'id' => Str::random(10)
            ]);
        }
        $this->cart->put($value['id'] , $value);
        session()->put('cart' , $this->cart);
        return $this;
    }

    public function update($key, $options)
    {
        $item = collect($this->get($key, false));
        if (is_numeric($options)) {
            $item = $item->merge([
                'quantity' => $item['quantity'] + $options
            ]);
        }
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $item = $item->merge($options);
        }
        $this->put($item->toArray());
        return $this;
    }

    public function count($key)
    {
        if (!$this->has($key)) return 0;
        return $this->get($key)['quantity'];
    }

    public function has($key)
    {
        if($key instanceof Model) {
            return ! is_null(
                $this->cart->where('subject_id' , $key->id)->where('subject_type' , get_class($key))->first()
            );
        }

        return ! is_null(
            $this->cart->firstWhere('id' , $key)
        );
    }

    public function get($key, $withRelationship = true)
    {
        $item = $key instanceof Model
            ? $this->cart->where('subject_id' , $key->id)->where('subject_type' , get_class($key))->first()
            : $this->cart->firstWhere('id' , $key);

        return $withRelationship ? $this->withRelationshipIfExist($item) : $item;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $cart = $this->cart;
        $cart = $cart->map(function($item) {
            return $this->withRelationshipIfExist($item);
        });

        return $cart;
    }

    protected function withRelationshipIfExist($item)
    {
        if(isset( $item['subject_id'] ) && isset($item['subject_type']) ) {
            $class = $item['subject_type'];
            $subject = (new $class())->find( $item['subject_id'] );

            $item[strtolower(class_basename($class))] = $subject;

            unset($item['subject_id']);
            unset($item['subject_type']);

            return $item;
        }
        return $item;
    }

    public function delete($key)
    {
        if ($this->has($key)) {
            $this->cart = $this->cart->filter(function ($item) use ($key){
                if ($key instanceof Model) {
                    return ($item['subject_id'] != $key->id ) && ($item['subject_type'] != get_class($key));
                }
                return $key != $item['id'];
            });
            session()->put('cart', $this->cart);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function flush()
    {
        $this->cart = collect([]);
        session()->put('cart', $this->cart);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I get this error.

> Undefined array key "course"

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if the 'course' key is being set in the ```$cart``` array. If 'course' is supposed to be another type of subject, you should adjust your code to handle this.

Comment: make sure you check if the 'product' and 'course' keys exists using `isset()`

Comment: How to check if the 'course' key?

Comment: in the foreach loop before assigning the `$cart['product']` and `$cart['course']`, check if `isset()`

Comment: I see 
Total price
0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, I'll check `product` or `course` first, if exists then sum total

```
@php
    $totalPrice = 0;
    foreach (App\Services\Cart\Cart::all() as $cart) {
       if (isset($cart['product'])) {
          $productPrice = intval($cart['product']->price);
          $totalPrice += $productPrice * $cart['quantity'];
       }
       if (isset($cart['course'])) {
          $coursePrice = intval($cart['course']->price);
          $totalPrice += $coursePrice * $cart['quantity'];
       }
    }
    $totalPrice = number_format($totalPrice);
@endphp
<div class="text-large"><strong>{{ $totalPrice }} $</strong></div>
```

Comment: You could also check whether quantity is set, if not you could skip (continue) the loop. (Just a small detail though)